# How to remove single character words from string with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Given the following input -

```
"I went to 1 ' and didn't see p"
```

,
what is the regular expression for PHP's preg_replace function to remove all single characters (and left over spaces) so that the output would be -

`"went to and didn't see".`

I have been searching for a solution to this but cannot find one. Similar examples haven't included explanations of the regular expression so i haven't been able to adapt them to my problem. So please, if you know how to do this, provide the regular expression but also break it down so that I can understand how it works.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$output = trim(preg_replace("/(^|\s+)(\S(\s+|$))+/", " ", $input));
```

- `(^|\s+)` means "beginning of string or space(s)"
- `(\s+|$)` means "end of string of space(s)"
- `\S` is single non-space character

Comment: This will leave a space at the end of the string, won't it?

Comment: thats why there's `trim()` call there

Comment: @poncha Won't that leave the first single quote in there? like "went to' and didn't see"

Comment: @poncha +1 Thanks for this, I wanted something to remove single characters from a search string. Would you know how I could modify this so at least 1 single character was left `a` in the search, `a d f g`? A search for `a d f te` would ideally only leave `te` rather than `a te`. If you have any thoughts I'd be thoroughly grateful!

Comment: @AshClarke i am not sure i quite understand... but if you wish to remove all single chars except `a` , then you should change `\S` into `[^a\s]` - this character class means *any character except a and whitespace*

Comment: It's ok, I went for a different approach to remove single character searches. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: If you want to allow numbers you can adjust it to `(^|\s+)(\D(\s+|$))+`

Comment: not suit for unicode

Comment: @djdance it is, if you add /u flag

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two passes

The first is to strip out all single characters

```
(?<=^| ).(?=$| ) replace with empty string
```

The second one is to leave only single spaces

```
[ ]{2,} replace with single space
```

You will end up with a string that has possibly spaces in the beginning or the end. I would just trim this with your language instead of doing that with a regex

As an example, the first regex is written in php like

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=^| ).(?=$| )/sm', '', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

try with help of [`implode`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php),  [`explode`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$str ="I went to 1 ' and didn't see p";
$arr = explode(' ',$str);
function singleWord($var)
{
  if(1 !== strlen($var))
  return $var;
}
$final = array_filter($arr,'singleWord');

echo implode(' ',$final);
//return "went to and didn't see"(length=19)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regexp

```
'\s+\S\s+' -> ' '
```

Comment: this doesn't catch this case, though: 'word 1, word' - try playing with '\b' if you need it supported