# Java : How to remove all characters in String except a a-z,digits and German characters

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which we are currently integrating OCR functionality. OCR's have a habit of throwing wild-characters for wrong detections and when there is an image in background. After processing the image, we have considerably good data available, but there are still some errors. We would like to process the output as follows

1. Remove all single characters from the output String.
2. Remove any and all characters other than A-Z,a-z, German characters i.e  äöü, ÄÖÜ,ß.
3. Spaces and digits should be left untouched.

Code :

```
  File imageFile = new File(fileLocation);

            BufferedImage img  = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
            BufferedImage blackNWhite = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
            Graphics2D graphics = blackNWhite.createGraphics();
            graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            String blackAndWhiteImage =  zipLocation + String.valueOf(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32))+".png";
            File outputfile = new File(blackAndWhiteImage);
            ImageIO.write(blackNWhite, "png", outputfile);

            ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
            // Point to one folder above tessdata directory, must contain training data
            instance.setDatapath("/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/");
            // ISO 693-3 standard
            instance.setLanguage("deu");
            String result = instance.doOCR(outputfile);
            //System.out.println(result);
             result = result.replaceAll("\\P{ASCII}","");
            System.out.println("Result is "+result);
            return result;
```

Thank you.

*Update*

Wild characters left by the regex :

```
 |
| '(°Ul") 
_} °
=# '
( )
...................................__+_......_._._.__._._._+._._.
```

Comment: regex  would be ``[öÖäÄüÜßa-zA-Z]``

Answer (score 2):

Ad. 1.
`result.replaceAll("\\s[a-zA-ZöÖäÄüÜß]\\s", "");`
Ad. 2.
`result.replaceAll("[^a-zA-ZöÖäÄüÜß]", "");`

Comment: I think step 1 should also remove digits, and preserve one of the spaces. Something like `\\s[a-zA-Z\döÖäÄüÜß]\b` would also work at the end of a sentence where there's no space after the last character.

Comment: Thank you, I dont want to remove digits. Should I use 2nd or 1st for that? THank you.

Comment: @WeareBorg You have to use both of them. It's a 2-step process.

Comment: @xenteros first regex doesn't work for eg. "a b c" - it will remove only "b".

Comment: It removed digits and spaces as well. I don't want to remove digits and spaces.  My mistake when creating post like that, edited. Thank you.

Comment: Regex base on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11188763/4178245) should work for the first step: `result.replaceAll("(^|\\s+)([a-zA-ZöÖäÄüÜß](\\s+|$))+", "");`

Comment: @kolejnik With that pattern, `ab c de` becomes `abde`. You have to preserve one of the spaces (or replace with space).

Comment: @kolejnik : I tried out your regex, it did not remove a lot of wild characters from the String. Also, while creating the post, I made an error that digits should be removed. I have edited the post to reflect that digits should be left untouched. I am editing the main post to display the wild-characters left by the regex. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex I finally used to solve this problem :

```
result = result.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß@\\s]", "");
```

Thank you.